# How to generate file using script using puppet

Tags: puppet

I have the following resource:

```
exec{'regen-nagios-hosts':
  command     => '/usr/local/bin/generate-nagios-host-definitions-from-hostfile < /etc/hosts > /etc/nagios3/conf.d/sv-hosts.cfg',
  user        => 'root',
  before      => Class['nagios::server'],
  notify      => Service['nagios3'],
  require     => File['/etc/hosts'],
}
```

Ideally, I'd want to restart Nagios only if the file changed. It seems what I really want is a file resource, but file resources have a template or the actual content, not a script. How can I generate the file (or change my method) to restart Nagios only when `/etc/nagios3/conf.d/sv-hosts.cfg` changes?

Comment: What's in the file?

Comment: Can you use the [concatenation pattern](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Generating_a_config_file_from_fragments) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each time your script runs it will generate the file exactly the same way for a given hosts file you could make a minor adjustment.

```
# generate the file into some arbitrary location, that is not actually referenced by nagios
exec{'regen-nagios-hosts':
  command     => '/usr/local/bin/generate-nagios-host-definitions-from-hostfile < /etc/hosts > /etc/nagios3/generatedtmpsv-hosts.cfg',
  user        => 'root',
  before      => Class['nagios::server'],
  require     => File['/etc/hosts'],
}

# have a file resource use the generated file to update the production file
# the update will only happen when the checksums have changed
# on update notify the service to restart.
file { '/etc/nagios3/conf.d/sv-hosts.cfg'':
  ensure => present,
  source => '/etc/nagios3/generatedtmp/sv-hosts.cfg'
  require => Exec['regen-nagios-hosts'],
  notify => Service['nagios3'],
}
```

In the long term though it might be better to try and find ways to convert your script into a template.  Or find some other way that fits better into the puppet way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your exec definition is that it will change/update the file regardless if the content was actually changed. Have a look at the `onlyif` in [typedef specification](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec)

If I were you I would generate the `sv-hosts.cfg` file in a temporary file and compare it with the current one. If there are some differences just copy the tmp file to the new location and restart the nagios.

Also have a look at the [type reference documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#nagioscommand), because there are so many nagios specific types and maybe one of them will do the trick for you :)

Comment: If you are looking at the onlyif option then something like this might be what you want? `onlyif => 'test /etc/hosts -nt /etc/nagios3/conf.d/sv-hosts.cfg'`